# Thumbnail issue on Tubepress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, tubepress

Tubepress displays gallery of videos, but when I clicked the thumbnails, it doesnt play the videos. It seems to be a link, but it doesnt play/replace the current video on top. Ive search at Wordpress Support, seems everyone is also having a problem on Tubepress thumbnails, but cant find any support on mine. Thanks for the help in advance. Here's the site by the way. http://www.ironwillfootball.ca/video-gallery